# Decode HTML entities stored in MySQL with Twig (in Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a MySQL database with some content created with ckeditor. The text is stored like this `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;L&amp;rsquo;automatisation des syst&amp;egrave;mes dans le monde` so with HTML entities.

With Twig, in a Symfony project, when I want to display my data, I use for this field `{{ article.mytext|raw}}` but it display `<p><strong>L&rsquo;automatisation des syst&egrave;mes dans le monde` so it's not fully decoded and interpreted...

With PHP I have no problem and a `html_entity_decode($mytext);` do the job perfectly.

Can you help me ? What is wrong ?

As requested, more of the code : 
in MySQL in a utf8_general_ci column "vTexte"
    `&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;L&amp;rsquo;automatisation des syst&amp;egrave;mes dans le monde`

in my controler in symfony :

```
namespace MU\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use MU\CoreBundle\Entity\Veille;

class CoreController extends Controller
{

public function actufreeAction()
{

  $repository = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('MUCoreBundle:Veille')
  ;

  $listactufree = $repository->findBy(
          array('vStatus' => '4'), // Critere
          array('vDatePublished' => 'desc'),        // Tri
          5,                              // Limite
          0                               // Offset
        );  



    $content = $this->get('templating')->render('MUCoreBundle::news.html.twig', array(
  'listactufree'  => $listactufree,
));
    return new Response($content);
}

}
```

In my Twig file news.html.twig

```
{% for veille in listactufree %}

    {{ veille.vTexte | raw }}

{% endfor %}
```

With that, it show : 
    `<p><strong>L&rsquo;automatisation des syst&egrave;mes dans le monde`

and I want :

**L’automatisation des systèmes dans le monde**

Comment: you really should provide more of the source, rather than little snippets.

Comment: I'll provide a solution for you soon, but so that I can ensure it's the best one for you, could you tell me if you have control over how this HTML is stored? Are you using `html_entity_encode` somewhere before sending it to the DB?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I have control over this HTML is stored but I have 800 articles stored like this... it's why I would really like to find a way to display them correctly. This HTML is stored using CKEditor 4 and a PDO prepared request in "normal" PHP/MyQSL. I used also a `htmlspecialchars` before the insertion but I already tried without it and it change nothing.

Comment: I don't use a `html_entity_decode` before the insertion, but I used one to display this HTML data from my DB and it's work. Without the `html_entity_decode` is show the result I have in Symfony after using the raw filter `<p><strong>L&rsquo;automatisation des syst&egrave;mes dans le monde` it's why I was trying previouly to use 2 times the raw filter...

Comment: and I have also tried to replace the content my DB by the content I have after using the raw filter : `p><strong>L&rsquo;automatisation des syst&egrave;mes dans le monde` and when I use the raw filter on this, it works. It's why i was confused and tried to use the raw filter 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Carefully control encodings.

The problem you are encountering is the simplest form of the nightmare that is character encoding. Rule one in handling encoding issues is to always control the encoding. In your case, this HTML should really be stored un-encoded in the DB, allowing for a single use of the twig `raw` output filter.

Consider the implications if you *don't* know whether the HTML needs to be decoded. For instance, if someone *intended* to show a `<` (`&lt;`) in the text, and the html *wasn't* encoded, then applying `html_entity_decode` will turn that *encoded* `<` into a real one, and break the HTML. (Browsers will think you're starting a new TAG).

## Forms submitting html

I'm going to guess that elsewhere in your app, there are forms which allow people to submit HTML. HTML forms encode data before posting, PHP `$_POST` handling usually auto applies `htmlentities` onto posted fields.

Whatever methods of your application are handling the storing of such Posted HTML, or add/changes these entities, should use `html_entity_decode` to ensure it is stored as raw html.

This way, you always know that HTML is stored in you database in exactly the state it needs to be rendered on the page. If it needs to be encoded and decoded again somewhere for some reason, you're not left hoping that some of the content won't be double-decoded. (Or as in your case, missing a decode step and spitting out raw HTML).

## Rendering HTML in twig

One way or another, you need to get that content to your twig, passed through the `raw` filter, in the exact state it needs to be put on the page. While this *can* be done in twig, or with twig functions, this really should be done in the Controller.

Consider that path this data is traveling:

1. Form (raw HTML)
2. PHP POST (encoded HTML)
3. DB (encoded HTML)
4. SELECT Query
5. PHP Controller (encoded HTML)
6. Twig
7. Rendered HTML

The earlier you can get the data in the correct state, the better. Doing so makes the data easier to work with, reduces the performance impact, and prevents code-duplication later in those steps. (What happens if you want to use this html in other Controllers or Twig templates? Code duplication.) Hense, my first suggestion to get it in the database cleanly.

If clean data is not an option...

## Clean the data in your controller, maybe even with a static function in the entity.

The only other clean-*ish* way to handle this, is to loop through and decode the html before passing it to Twig. Doing it this way however, or later in the Tiwg template as you're currently doing, you run the risk of double-decoding that I mentioned earlier.

#### Veille

```
Class Veille
{

    . . .

    public static function decodeArray(?array $vielleList): ?array
    {
        foreach ($vielleList as $vielle) {
            if (!$vielle instanceof self) {
                continue;
            }

            $vielle->setVText(html_entity_decode($vielle->getVText()));
        }

        return $vielleList;
    }

    public function getVText(): ?string
    {
        return htmlentities("<h3>Encoded HTML Test</h3>Good data &gt; parsing bad data.");
    }

    public function setVText(?string $text): void
    {

    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
$listactufree = $repository->findBy(
    array('vStatus' => '4'), // Critere
    array('vDatePublished' => 'desc'),        // Tri
    5,                              // Limite
    0                               // Offset
);


$listactufree = Veille::decodeArray($listactufree);
```

#### Twig

```
{% for veille in listactufree %}

    {{ veille.vTexte|raw }}

{% endfor %}
```

## Note, this same code could clean your data.

Plugging the contents of the `decodeArray` method into a command, and running that command, along with persist/flush, would store decoded HTML for all of your entities. Just make sure you only decode ONCE, and any methods which can add or edit these entities store the HTML ***unencoded***. That's the key. Unencoded data.

Comment: Super, thank you for these great explanations ! First I added a `html_entity_decode` before saving the content of my form in the database. And I tried your code in Symfony and the decodeArray function works well, I was confused with the getter and setter you write, should I need them ?  It works with the one I had :
    `public function getVTexte()
    {
        return $this->vTexte;
    }`  ? And finally, I just write a command to transform the data in my database in decoded HTML !

Comment: I only included the `vtexe` getter and setter for code completeness, so it was clear what the `decodeArray` function expected, and returned. You don't need my getters and setters, just use yours.  

Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

{{ html_var|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')}}

Answer (score 1):

Using automatic escaping with convert_encoding should decode:

```
{% autoescape false %}
  {{ value|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

If you don't use `autoescape false`, it will not decode the html entities.  I used this for decoding `&#039;` to `'`.

Sources: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/convert_encoding.html

Answer (score 0):

You had to set the autoescape to false:

see there: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ html_var }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: It display the same result as I have by using `{{ html_var | raw }}` I have still `<p><strong>L&rsquo;automatisation des syst&egrave;mes dans le monde` :-(